# function() {} vs functionName: () {} in prototype

Tags: javascript

I have one doubt about javascript which I hope someone can explain me. I have a Watcher class which works just as expected:

```
function Watcher(paths) {
    let watcher_instance = Object.create(Watcher.prototype);
    watcher_instance.paths = paths;
    return watcher_instance;
}


Watcher.prototype = {
    init_watcher() {
        console.log(this.paths)
    }
}
```

Then, when I do

```
let watcher = new Watcher(paths);
watchers.init_watcher();  // prints the paths Array
```

all works as expected.

But I change the prototype to:

```
Watcher.prototype = {
    init_watcher: () => {
        console.log(this.paths) // prints undefined
    }
}
```

this.path seems not to be initialized at all. Anybody knows why?

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname), but haven't seen any reference to this behaviour.

Comment: Read also `arrow functions`. It's cause, why you got `undefined`

Comment: "An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. These function expressions are best suited for *non-method* functions, and they cannot be used as constructors." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, this works just fine: Watcher.prototype = {
    init_watcher: function() {
        console.log(this.paths)
    }
}